# Separação Completa em Hurdle Model

Tags: r

Em uma análise de Hurdle Model, como pode-se trabalhar com uma das variáveis do modelo que apresenta separação completa (ou quase completa) no modelo binomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resposta curta**

Não. A função de verossimilhança não vai conseguir se maximizada e isto vai afetar a estimação dos parâmetros da parte logística do modelo.

**Resposta Não Tão Curta**

Depende. É possível lidar com separação completa em regressão logística se tu utilizar uma verossimilhança penalizada. Tem várias maneiras de fazer isto no R, embora nenhuma delas esteja implementada no pacote `pscl` (pelo menos dentro do meu conhecimento).

Outra maneira mais fácil de lidar com isso é deixar a variável problemática de fora da análise.

Uma terceira alternativa é, caso a variável que gera a separação completa seja categórica, combiná-la com outras variáveis categóricas, de maneira que isto faça sentido no contexto do teu problema.

Comment: Opa, Marcus, brigadão pelas dicas! Então, a variável em questão é quantitativa, então não posso combiná-la com outras. Eu já pensei em deixá-la fora da análise, porém ela é muito importante no meu modelo, e inclusive existem outros trabalhos que demonstram isso em contextos semelhantes com o que estou trabalhando. Dá pra trabalhar com verossimilhança penalizada dentro da abordagem Hurdle? Eu procurei sobre isso, mas confesso que não achei resultados satisfatórios :( Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Comment: Em teoria, dá sim pra trabalhar com a verossimilhança padronizada usando modelos hurdle, porque ele separa a verossimilhança das contagens e das proporções em duas verossimilhanças independentes. Mas eu _acho_  que o Achim Zeileis não implementou isto no pacote `pscl`, que é o pacote que conheço pra trabalhar com modelos hurdle. Assim, alguém teria que programar esta função específica, encontrar as verossimilhanças e tal, para poder fazer este tipo de ajuste. Mas fazer isso, por si só, já daria uma dissertação de mestrado (quiçá tese de doutorado) em um departamento de estatística.

Comment: Minha dissertação, que é da Ecologia, daqui a pouco vai se transformar em um trabalho de estatística mesmo, hahaha. Ok, já consegui compreender melhor, e vou decidir o caminho mais lógico pra tratar essa variável. Brigadão! :)

Comment: Te entendo. Pra escrever a minha tese, que foi na estatística, tive que aprender biologia, bioinformática e química, só pra entender como desenvolver um novo método estatístico para lidar com dados de RNA-Seq. Quem quer trabalhar com multidisciplinaridade acaba passando por isso.

Comment: Hahahaha, toda razão!